# install sqlxml windows azure with startup task

Tags: azure

I have a startup task to install sql xml 3.0 sp3 but this not work.

In my project i have a folder "setup" which contains two files, setup.cmd and sqlxml.msi. In setup.cmd i have the following script:

```
start /w msiexec /i sqlxml.msi /qn
```

And in my servicedefinition:

```
<Task commandLine="setup\setup.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure the files are actually being deployed. In Visual Studio, open their properties and make sure Copy to Output Directory is set to "Copy always". If in doubt, extract your deployment package to a directory (it is a ZIP file) and see if the files are there.
2. When setup.cmd runs, the current directory will be your web application's [bin folder](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/0e13b1c0-54cf-477f-915b-e014f831ee30) so make sure to use a `CD setup` command inside setup.cmd.
3. Follow the debugging tips mentioned in [Windows Azure Startup Tasks: Tips, Tricks, and Gotchas](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/windows-azure-startup-tasks-tips-tricks-and-gotchas).